# ngx Datatable update header dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ngx-datatable

I am using the component ngx-datatable in my angular app and I am trying to update the header texts dynamically. 
What I was trying was the following:

```
<ngx-datatable-column prop="day_1" name="{{day_1_header}}">
```

and updating the day_1_header property dynamically, but when I do so the change is never reflected.
I have also tried adding a ViewChild and changing the name directly like so:

```
HTML:
<ngx-datatable-column #dataTable1 prop="day_1" name="{{day_1_header}}">
TS:
@ViewChild('dataTable1') dataTable1;
[..]
this.dataTable1.nativeElement.name = "test";
```

When I check the properties of my dataTable1 object the new name is set.

So can anyone tell me how to rerender/sync the datatable headers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Damn...
Tried forever, asked the question and found a solution right away.
It worked by adding an explicit header-template to the column like this:

```
<ngx-datatable-column>
      <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
        {{day_1_header}}
      </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Maybe it helps someone someday.

Comment: yes indeed! Thank you for sharing this solution. This has saved me quite a bit time!.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the other answer (which seems pretty direct and logical) didn't work for me. Maybe breaking change in higher version.
[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1579) gives another perspective on how to achieve it.
There's also [this example](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#templateref) in the [source code](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/app/templates/template-obj.component.ts) that shows it.

Basically, you'll need the custom template for the column header

```
<ngx-datatable
        class="material"
        [rows]="rows"
        [columns]="columns"
        [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force"
        [headerHeight]="50"
        [footerHeight]="50"
        rowHeight="auto"
      >
</ngx-datatable>

<!-- custom column header template -->
<ng-template #hdrTpl let-column="column"> <strong>Fancy</strong>: {{ column.name }} !! </ng-template>
```

Then access it in your component class with `@ViewChild()` decorated property.

```
export class TemplateRefTemplatesComponent {
  @ViewChild('hdrTpl', { static: true }) hdrTpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  rows = [];
  columns = [];

  ColumnMode = ColumnMode;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // You'll need to map over all columns to use it in all
    this.columns = this.columns.map(columns => ({...columns, headerTemplate: this.hdrTpl});
  }
}
```